# What are options for VB-ASP applications for consuming .NET web services?

Tags: asp-classic, distributed-transactions

I have a traditional ASP application which is expected to consume a .net web service. 
What support does ASP provide for such a scenario?

I rememeber VB script supporting a transaction attribute at the start of the page.
Can i use the transaction to include the web service call as well?

Any pointers would be appreciated.
thanks

Paritosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing a COM or COM+ component in C#, and having it do all the web service work. That way you get the benefit of all the tools available to modern programs while still being able to use it from ancient ones. You can even get transaction support that way, which I don't think you'll get from the SOAP Toolkit, since there was no distributed transaction support in SOAP at all back in 2002/2003.

Comment: Thanks John. Did not realise SOAP Toolkit is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Got a good pointer on consuming webservices in classic asp
http://www.dotnetjunkies.ddj.com/Tutorial/99CA4563-FBD4-411F-A9C6-FF9E8A0E664F.dcik

Now need to try transaction support......

Comment: The only problem there is that the article is from 2002, and is about the unsupported SOAP Toolkit.